# Updating the LaunchConfig using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

We have a set of Cloudformation templates to build multiple modules and maintain the base template to hold the common properties like AMI ID, VPC ID etc. Modulewise templates will make a function call to get the required property from Base stack. Here is an example of LaunchConfig creation properties.

```
"Properties" : {
    "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "NetworkStackInfo", "UsePublicIP" ] },
    "KeyName"                  : { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "BaseStackInfo", "StackKey" ] },
    "InstanceMonitoring"       : { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "BaseStackInfo", "EnableDetailedMonitoring" ] },
    "ImageId" : { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "BaseStackInfo", "MVCustomAMI" ] } 
}
```

I am trying to update the AMI id, VPC id and re-build all the stacks. I have done Base stack update and it is reflecting the new AMI/VPC IDs in the stack Outputs. Now when I try to update the module-wise stacks, it is not detecting the new property changes in Base stack so it is not taking any action when I try to update the stack.

Can somebody help me with finding out if I am missing any step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question so that it may help someone.

Cloudformation usually caches the Outputs of the dependent stacks for any Stack update operations. Unless the corresponding resource is renamed or changed, the new values would not be pulled instead existing cached entries would be used.
To get around this, we need to either rename the logical resource name or add some test property to the resource so that it will Delete that resource and pull the latest values from that dependent stack.